# Eloquent updateOrCreate hide columns while updating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using the `updateOrCreate()` function to update the record if a record is already available in the table based on some condition. However, I do not want to update one of my columns that contains a unique value.

I want to perform the same action to this column like `created_at` is working
while creating the records value is adding to the `created_at` column but while updating it contains the same.

To prevent this issue I removed that column name from `$fillable` in my model. But, in this case, it is not adding any value to this column.

```php
protected $fillable = ['uid', 'channel', 'updated_at'];

$data = [
    'uid' => Helper::generateUid(),
    'channel' => $info['channel'],
    'created_at' => time(),
    'updated_at' => time(),
];

$cond = ['channel' => $info['channel']];

$isAdded = Templates::updateOrCreate($cond, $data);
```

**Expected result**
I don't want to update uid column if details already there.

**Actual result**
If details are not there it adds value to uid column and other columns also and if details are available then also it is updating uid column.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the `updateOrCreate` method. You'll need to be slightly more explicit. You can use the `firstOrNew` method to retrieve or instantiate a new object. And then you can use the `exists` property to determine if it is an existing or new object.

```
$template = Templates::firstOrNew(['channel' => $info['channel']]);

if (!$template->exists) {
    $template->uid = Helper::generateUid();
}

$template->save();
```

I left out the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields because they are automatically handled by Laravel.